# What is the id of the close button on a modal dialog?

Tags: 2010, javascript, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog and I want to change some of its properties through javascript. I have found the jquery code

```
jQuery("a[id^='DlgClose']")
```

but when I try to use the javascript

```
document.getElementById("DlgClose")
```

it comes back null. I am not sure whether I am converting jquery to javascript wrong or I have the wrong id.

I am using Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 6):

The id of the close button is not just "DlgClose" it is "DlgClose< GUID >". For example, `DlgClose355aef3c-ef2f-4293-a7b1-ffa236195624`

In your jQuery code, you are using a begins-with selector `^` which gets all elements whose id starts with a particular string. (DlgClose in this case.)

While in your JavaScript code, you are getting all the elements whose id is exactly "DlgClose". `document.getElementById` checks for that exact id and gets elements if any. That is why you are getting a null value.

I would suggest you stick to jQuery as it will really make life easier for you. But still if you want to perform the same functionality with pure JavaScript, then have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111668/find-all-elements-whose-id-begins-with-a-common-string